# Add glow effect to hexagon class

Tags: html, css

I am currently attempting to add a uniform glow effect around a hexagon created with CSS classes but due to the way the hexagon is drawn, the glow effect ends up with odd breaks that I cannot seem to fix.

```css
.hexagon {
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 5px;
 height: 125px;
 width: 75px;
 margin: 50px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: black;
 border-bottom-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon:before, .hexagon:after {
 content: "";
 border: inherit;
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 left: -5px;
 background: inherit;
 border-radius: inherit;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.hexagon:before {
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hexagon:after {
 transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon:hover, .hexagon:hover:before, .hexagon:hover:after {
 box-shadow: 0 10px 2px -2px rgba(255,0,0,0.5), 0 -10px 2px -2px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class=hexagon></div>
```

Comment: the purpose is to have an hexagone with fixed shadow or you want to fix THIS one especially ?

Comment: A hexagon shape in general. From what I've seen, it's a lot harder to create a flat-base hexagon with CSS classes, especially when you want a knock-out fill like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add more padding inside the element and adjust the border radius. All line will cross and the radius will fix the shape :

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 125px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  border: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.hexagon:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon:hover,
.hexagon:hover:before,
.hexagon:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 2px -2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 -10px 2px -2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class=hexagon></div>
```

You can of course control the radius of your shape by changing simultaneously the padding and border-radius

Comment: Excellent! Is there any way I can get this to work without the corner overlaps having a higher opacity than the rest of the glow? (If not, then no worries. I can make do with this for sure.)

Comment: yes i was also thinking about this higher opacity ... by the way you control it by reducing the paddin and radius. You may play with these value until you make the "higher opcity" less than actually